# npm install Error: Cannot find module './support/cli'.- How copy an angular project with another name

Tags: angular, npm-install

I have a angular 2 project CarlotaVinaProj. I did right npm install in this project.

Now I want to copy this project with another name. I executed

```
sudo cp -r . /Users/carlotavina/Documents/carlota/irvine/javaenterprisedevelopment/curso7-angular/Hw1_CarlotaVina
```

When I do npm install to generate node-modules I get the following error

```
Carlotas-MacBook-Pro:Hw1_CarlotaVina carlotavina$ npm install

> undefined postinstall /Users/carlotavina/Documents/carlota/irvine/javaenterprisedevelopment/curso7-angular/Hw1_CarlotaVina
> typings install

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './support/cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/carlotavina/Documents/carlota/irvine/javaenterprisedevelopment/curso7-angular/Hw1_CarlotaVina/node_modules/.bin/typings:10:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

How can I copy this project with another name?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you'd copy anything else. Just copy the project folder and you're good. (Be sure to include the dot files)

If you're making a fork of the project, you'll want to change some configs: the project name in package.json and the .angular-cli.json, and the component/directive prefix in .angular-cli.json and tslint files.

The best approach would to copy everything from the project file except the node modules .Then paste the project in a folder and them go that particular path and run the command “npm install”.

Comment: After checking the copy I note that there are folders with denied permission when I do a cd

Comment: Windows? Linux?

Comment: Problem still exists? If it's oke please give me an accept :)